# adding labels to node in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, force-layout

I am a newbie in d3.js

I am trying to add labels to my nodes.
But whatever I tried is not working..
My code is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ymtg5/1/

Its a mash up between http://bl.ocks.org/christophermanning/4208494
and force directed graphs.
Basically I am reading a json file and creating the said graph.
Now I want to add labels to node exactly like http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642
I tried adding these lines

```
node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name });
```

But its not working.
Any help. suggestions..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem is that your JSON classes don't have a "name".

**Right, this was not the problem**

The relevant part of your code is as follows:

```
var node = svg.selectAll("path.node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("path").attr("class", "node")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.value); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(fill(d.value)).darker(); })
    .call(force.drag);

 // HERE should go node manipulation to add the text

force
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

function tick() {

  //node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; );
  node.attr("d", function(d) { return clip({"type":"F {"type":"Point","coordin...         
  link.attr("d", function(d) { return clip({"type":"Feature","geometry":{ ...
```

I have inserted a comment line where your node manipulation should go, if you want to add labels to the nodes. You are doing that inside the tick function (well, I think you are trying to do it there, the code isn't in the fiddle), and that function should be only for manipulation of the attr of the nodes. The place to create the text and append it to the node is outside of the function.

Comment: My json file looks like this 
{
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Myriel","group":1},
    {"name":"Napoleon","group":1},.....

Comment: Sorry, hadn't seen the reference to the miserables :-) Is your code included in the fiddle ? I cann't find it

Comment: @vals.. HI you can get the miserables.json from here 
http://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables/miserables.json

Comment: No the json data, I wanted to know where your code 'node.append("text")' was

Comment: Line 163.. BUt i think it the issue is line 160.. which is commented but thats what is needed i think to get this thing to wrk.. thanks